# Удалять строковые символы при вводе

Tags: angular

Написал дерективу

```
export class NumberDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input')
  private onInput() {
    let value: any = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    if(value == '') return;
    if(isNaN(value) || value.includes(' ')) {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    }
  }
}
```

Хочу чтобы при заполнении input моментально стерались все не числовые символы и это работает, но с багом. Input пустой, но в консоли всё равно выводится последний символ.

Comment: удалите всё кроме строки с replace или используйте  `<input type="number">`

Comment: @InDevX работает, но почему мой вариант выдавал 1 символ?

Comment: Не знаю, это надо дебажить, но вы слишком много лишнего делали (и условия странные). И ещё совет - поменьше используйте any, лучше лишний раз модель сделать, или обычные типы использовать.

Comment: @InDevX обнаружилось, что e (как экспонента) является числом для type="number" и при вводе перед или между цифрами очищается всё поле. Интересно, не мог не поделиться)

Comment: Спасибо что поделились. Не сталкивался, буду знать)